# UnitTest : Can't add many to many relations : Integrity error (seems delete do not do his job)

Tags: python, unit-testing, foreign-keys, sqlalchemy, python-elixir

I have two tables : Person & Team ; each has a Many-To-Many relation with the other.

I do this in the `setUp` function (called **before** each function of testing, 3 times in my case)

```
p = Person(fname=u"John", lname=u"Doe")
Team(name=u"Anon", persons=[p])
session.commit()
```

And my `tearDown` function (called **after** each function of testing)

```
Person.query.delete()
Team.query.delete()
session.commit()
```

The first test passes, but when `setUp` is called the second time, I got this :
`IntegrityError: (IntegrityError) columns person_id, team_id are not unique u'INSERT INTO team_persons__person_teams (person_id, team_id) VALUES (?, ?)' (5, 1)`

It seems like delete did not really delete the rows the first time. I can't figure out why this happens.

Answer (score 0):

The rows in your `Person` and `Team` tables are being deleted, but the row from the association table is not.  This is because `query.delete()` does not handle relationship cascading.  See [Python's SQLAlchemy doesn't clean out the secondary (many-to-many) table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9918653/pythons-sqlalchemy-doesnt-clean-out-the-secondary-many-to-many-table) for a detailed explanation.

You should be able to solve this by using `session.delete(obj)` for each object you have added. Or better yet, for unit testing with an in-memory database, just drop and re-create all of your tables during `tearDown` and `setUp`.